# Object wont rotate on local axis

Tags: modeling, object-mode

I am trying to rotate the cylinder on the bottom of this thing 90 degrees, but it wont rotate correctly.

[image]

[image]

This is what happens when I try to rotate it 90 degrees in either the X or Y axis

[image]

I want the rotation to align with the direction of the leg, rather than clash towards it as an angle. If there is any sort of solution to this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: If you rotate a cylinder 90º in its Local Z axis it's going to rotate around the round faces. You care not going to see a difference. You'd want to rotate it in the Global space, first 901 on the X and then 30 on the Z

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can handle this situation.

First one:
Parent the cylinder to the cuboid and then change the orientation to parent. Now depending upon the axes of the parent, simply <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate and <kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>Y</kbd> to specify the axes and then type in 90.

[image]

Second:
It's almost similar to the first one. This time instead of parenting, select the cuboid and then just go to the orientation menu and click the Plus icon to have the orientation of the cuboid usable for any object. Just select the newly created custom orientation and do the same rotation stuff mentioned previously.

[image]

The only advantage you will get by using the second method is that you wont have to parent each and every object in a case where you have multiple objects. Otherwise just use the first method.

[image]

Here's a nice video by CG Cookie if you want all the details about this orientation stuff:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwLMk_tFvfU